# MacOS Cannot Install Jekyll Gem

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, jekyll, rbenv

I have tried everything to try to install the jekyll gem. I uninstalled/reinstalled rbenv, installed ruby 2.6.1, set it as global, run `xcode-select --install` about 1000 times, run `xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, and `gem update --system` among various other stack overflow fixes. None of which have worked.  Every time, I get this familiar error message:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -I 
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190302-90413-16ok71q.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ruby_http_parser.c
In file included from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:29:
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/defines.h:123:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [ruby_http_parser.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
```

EDIT:

I am using MacOS 10.14 and this is my gem environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.1 (2019-01-30 patchlevel 33) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/<username>/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/<username>/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: 
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
        - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
        - /Users/<username>/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
        - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
        - :update_sources => true
        - :verbose => true
        - :backtrace => false
        - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
        - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
        - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
        - /bin
        - /Users/<username>/.rbenv/shims
        - /Users/<username>/.rbenv/bin
        - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin
        - /usr/local/bin
        - /usr/bin
        - /bin
        - /usr/sbin
        - /sbin
        - /opt/X11/bin
        - /usr/local/share/dotnet
        - /usr/local/go/bin
        - /Users/<username>/.rbenv/bin
        - /Users/<username>/.rbenv/shims
        - /Users/<username>/.rbenv/shims
        - /Users/<username>/.rbenv/bin
        - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin
        - /usr/local/bin
        - /usr/bin
        - /bin
        - /usr/sbin
        - /sbin
        - /usr/local/go/bin
        - /usr/local/share/dotnet
        - /opt/X11/bin
        - /Users/<username>/.rbenv/bin
        - /Users/<username>/.rbenv/shims
        - /bin
```

Not sure why I have so many duplicates in my $PATH but probably because of my bash_profile.

Comment: please post the output of `gem env`

Comment: also what version of MacOS are you on?

Comment: I added them in an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your PATH  setup is loading system ruby and not your rbenv ruby.

Try to remove this line from your .bash_profile since you don't want to use system ruby but the version from RBENV.

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
```

If that doesn't work, I'm not sure why you have so duplicates in your path, perhaps from multiple attempts to use RBENV.

I would suggest first, to  reinstall RBENV. You'll first need to [uninstall RBENV](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/148) by doing the following:

```
grep rbenv ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.zshrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/*
```

Remove any lines related to RBENV in files which may have them.

Remove rbenv

```
rm -rf ~/.rbenv
```

If you used homebrew to install rbenv, then

```
brew uninstall rbenv
```

Then `brew doctor` and see if there's anything else of concern reported.

Close all running terminals, then open a new one.  Then check `gem env` again and you should see a cleaner state with nothing related to RBENV only your system ruby.

Or if you prefer, you might try RVM first instead, to do that see  https://rvm.io/rvm/install

You might need to restart terminal after that, then go to your middleman project folder and run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Is there a reason you'd suggest to use RVM instead of rbenv? Couldn't I just try to edit my PATH to point to the rbenv ruby?

Comment: I changed `/usr/local/opt/ruby` in my PATH to `~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1` and gem install now runs successfully! I'll mark you answer as correct but you may want to edit it.

Comment: @genghiskhan I updated my answer, glad it pointed you in the right direction and got it working. But you probably don't want to specifically select version in your profile, let RBENV pick it